# creating a 2d array/matrix without given size

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a matrix that will be defined from user input, I've been trying many methods, the user should input line by line with spaces in between numbers, the program should stop inputting when it gets a -1 as input so the input should be like:

```
3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4
6 7 8 9
-1
```

and this is exactly how my created matrix should look like, please help. The thing is initially I dont know the size of the matrix, the user decides on the size based on what they input. code should be in java.

Here is some code I used, I used it to find the size of the matrix so I can actually make the matrix, it stores inputs in an array though so I dont know now how I can export them from the array to the 2d array.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<String>strArray = new ArrayList<>(); //stores-inputs
        
        String input = in.nextLine();
        input.replaceAll(" ", "");
        

        while(!input.equals("-1")){
            strArray.add(input);
            input = in.nextLine();
            input.replaceAll(" ", "");
        }
        int row = strArray.size();
        String col = input.replaceAll(" ", "");
        int noCol = col.length();
        int[][] matrix = new int[row][noCol];
}}
```

Comment: Could you share with us what code you've tried so far?

Comment: You can't do it directly.  Your problem is that you don't know in advance how many columns one row will have, nor how many rows you will have.  Since arrays are fixed size, you can only declare them after you know how large they will be.  Thus you need intermediate storage - either something that can be extended, like an ArrayList, or else arrays that are 'larger than you'll ever need'.  That should be enough of a hint to go and try some code.

Comment: @EwanBrown I have updated the question, please see the code there.

Comment: @passer-by I tried using an ArrayList but also didnt work out, I have a problem with actually loading the matrix

Comment: What happens when a row that doesn't contain -1 contains more or less numbers in it than the previous rows?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way

- it takes in a line of separated by one or more spaces
- splits the line and converts to an `int` array
- then ensures capacity of the existing target and assigns the array.
- it stops when the line equals `end`. This allows for input of -1

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int[][] finalArray = new int[0][];
String line;
while (!(line = input.nextLine()).contains("end")) {
    int[] arr = Arrays.stream(line.split("\\s+")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
    finalArray = Arrays.copyOf(finalArray,finalArray.length+1);
    finalArray[finalArray.length-1] = arr;
}
for (int[] a : finalArray) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
}
```

I would recommend either prompting for the row and col count and then allocate the array or use `ArrayLists` which grow dynamically.

Note:  Anything other than an `int` value to place in the array will throw an exception

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `List<List<Integer>>`?

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {       
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<List<Integer>> mat = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    
    System.out.print("Row Values (-1 to quit): ");
    String input = in.nextLine().trim();
    while (!input.equals("-1")) {
      List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      for(String strValue : input.split("\\s+")) {
        try {
          values.add(Integer.parseInt(strValue));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
      }
      if (values.size() > 0) {
        mat.add(values);
      }
      System.out.print("Row Values (-1 to quit): ");
      input = in.nextLine().trim();
    }

    for(List<Integer> row : mat) {
      System.out.println(row);
    }
  }
```

Sample run:

```
Row Values (-1 to quit): 3 4 5 6
Row Values (-1 to quit): 1 2 3 4
Row Values (-1 to quit): 6 7 8 9
Row Values (-1 to quit): -1
[3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: I'm reading this code and I gotta say I am learning a lot, bunch of stuff in the code that I'm seeing for the first time and I'm looking them up now, THANKS!!

Comment: Ask questions if you need to.

Comment: please explain to me this for loop *** for(String strValue : input.split("\\s+")) *** its a ForEach loop for a string? I usually use ForEach loops when working with Arrays and not individual strings

Comment: We are calling the `split()` method against the string called "input", using white space (as a regular expression) as the delimiter, which breaks up the string into different parts.  Split returns an array of strings which we iterate over using the enhanced for loop.

Comment: So the for loop is working with an array, just not one declared and initialized separately.

Comment: ohhh I'm mos def taking note of this, so it splits the string "3 9 6 7" into like "3", "9", etc. then adds the numerical value of dat individual string into the List right

Comment: Yes! Perfectly understood.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting your question correctly, you can fill the matrix with this option:

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> nrsArray = new ArrayList<>();

    String input = in.nextLine();
    int row = 0;

    while (!input.equals("-1")) {
        char[] chars = input.replaceAll(" ", "").toCharArray();
        for (char c : chars) {
            nrsArray.add(Character.getNumericValue(c));
        }
        row++;
        input = in.nextLine();
    }

    int col = nrsArray.size() / row;
    int[][] matrix = new int[row][col];

    for (int y = 0; y < row; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < col; x++) {
            matrix[y][x] = nrsArray.get(x + y * col);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matrix));
```